# electron how to allow insecure https

Tags: electron

Loading https://github.com works fine for exmaple.
But loading an insecure https, the **page displays empty**.

I've done some research and tried the 3 flags (`webSecurity`, `allowDisplayingInsecureContent`, `allowRunningInsecureContent`)  below with no success.

Looking for any known solutions. Thank you.

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote;

    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            plugins: true,
            nodeIntegration: false,
            webSecurity: false,
            allowDisplayingInsecureContent: true,
            allowRunningInsecureContent: true
        }
    });

    win.loadURL('https://insecure...')
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: It turned out we didn't really needed the feature, so i gave it up months ago.

Comment: I found out in my situation it was not because the content was "insecure", but the SSL cert was actually invalid, which requires a separate workaround: overriding the default behavior of the "certificate-error" electron action, which is normally to stop loading the page.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In `main.js`, do:

```js
const { app } = require('electron')

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors')
```

Comment: you might also need `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('allow-insecure-localhost', 'true');` if trying to post to https localhost with self-signed ssl

Answer (score 5):

## 100% Solution


Not all other solutions helped except this one

Source: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#event-certificate-error

```
const { app } = require('electron')

app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
  
    // Prevent having error
    event.preventDefault()
    // and continue
    callback(true)

})
```