# Electron - detect ssl certificate errors and programmatically ignore errors per domain / whitelist

Tags: javascript, ssl, browser, electron

In Chrome if you open an https page that has an expired/incorrect certificate, a warning will be displayed, but the user can still override it and whitelist the page for the duration of the session.

In an Electron app, visiting a https page with an incorrect certificate will result in a blank page with no warnings.

Is there a way to:

1. Detect when the page is denied being loaded because of improper SSL (handling all corner cases, all types  of SSL errors, etc.)
2. Programmatically whitelist a domain (for the duration of the session, or at all), to ignore the security warnings and allow loading the pages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50419166/13246101, solution to help to disable certificate check in the application

Comment: @Maneesh This will disable all certificate checks. I want to allow the user to see the warning and whitelist specific domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `certificate-error` callback which can be used here to add a logic to whitelist certain domains

```
const { app } = require('electron')

app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
  if (url === 'https://github.com') {
    // Verification logic.
    event.preventDefault()
    callback(true)
  } else {
    callback(false)
  }
})
```

Documentation is available here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-certificate-error